# standardizing an indicator variable and coefficients to 0

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference, intervention-analysis, distributed-lag

I am fitting a distributed lead, lag models to understand the impact of an event that took place in 2017.

My outcome y is a continuous variable.

The event took place in 2017.

I am interested in understanding the reaction of the outcome at `2014, 2015 2016 2017, 2018, 2019`. Two years after the event and 3 years before the event.

```
     BMI     EvaluationDate     lag_2014  lag_2015 lag_2016  Event      lead_2018  lead_2019
     10.23   2018-01-01         0         0        0         0          1          0
     21.35   2016-02-01         0         0        1         0          0          0
     32.12   2019-07-01         0         0        0         0          0          1
     17.11   2017-10-01         0         0        0         1          0          0
     25.19   2016-07-01         0         0        1         0          0          0
     45.23   2018-05-01         0         0        0         0          1          0
     25.67   2014-01-01         1         0        0         0          0          0
     27.89   2015-12-01         0         1        0         0          0          0
     31.56   2016-03-01         0         0        1         0          0          0
     39.56   2018-04-01         0         0        0         0          1          0
     15.96   2015-10-01         0         1        0         0          0          0
     19.17   2017-11-01         0         0        0         1          0          0 
     21.19   2015-09-01         0         1        0         0          0          0
     37.19   2019-05-01         0         0        0         0          0          1
     29.13   2017-02-01         0         0        0         1          0          0
```

The literature says "At least one coefficient $j$ needs to be fixed as a standardization. We
follow the standard and drop the pre event indicator $(b_{it})^{-1}$ from the regression model, standardizing its coefficient $(b_{it})^{-1}$ to zero". After the standardization $b_{-1}  = 0$, the parameter $j$ is the effect $j$ time periods after the event compared to the level one period before the event.

What does it mean,
**Thus at least one coefficient $j$ needs to be fixed as a standardization** ,

**drop the pre event indicator $(b_{it})^{-1}$ from the regression model** and

**standardizing its coefficient $(b_{it})^{-1}$ to zero**

I understand **standardizing** typically means subtracting the values by 0 and dividing by the standard deviation but what is standardizing in this context when the `lag_2016` variable is all 0s and 1s.

How does this force the $(b_{lag2016})$ to zero ?